# Insert same variable into multiple columns in Postgres with python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to insert the same decimal value into multiple columns in the same PostgreSQL table using this python script to generate some testing data

```
 def insert_payout(payout):

     vals = [payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout,
        payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout,
        payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout] #works

       sql = '''INSERT INTO test_db.public.test_node
       (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25, col26, col27, col28, col29, col30, col31, col32)
  VALUES
       (val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val, val ) '''

  conn = None
 
     print(vals)#remove after testing
     try:
         # read database configuration
         params = setparams()#managed elsewhere just connects to the db working
         # connect to the PostgreSQL database
         conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
         # create a new cursor
         cur = conn.cursor()
         # execute the INSERT statement
         cur.execute(sql, vals)
         # commit the changes to the database
         conn.commit()
         # close communication with the database
         cur.close()
      except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
          print(error)
      finally:
          if conn is not None:
              conn.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         insert_payout(3.3)
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
  [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
   not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Casting to a decimal doesn't work and I reworked it to int and that doesn't work either.

Comment: This `(val, val, val, val,...)` needs to be `(%s , %s, %s, %s...)` per [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). @MikeOrganek it just needs to be a sequence of values, `list` or `tuple` will work.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I listed it using vals = [payout, etc] isnt that a list?

Comment: `vals = [payout, payout, ...]` is not the problem, it is the other end `(val, val...)` needs to be `(%s, %s...)`. You could simplify further by using named arguments where `vals = {"val": payout}` and `(%(val)s,  %(val)s, %(val)s ...)`. Then you would not have to build a list of inputs just the dict and the `payout` value would be picked up by `%(val)s`.

Comment: I believe you only have 31 `val` but 32 columns and 32 items in your list (unless I'm mistaken). That will likely be the next error to pop.

Comment: @JNevill good catch!

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am not sure where to update is it in the SQL statement? Or in the cursor statement? If you show a demo I will select you as the correct since I am pretty sure you did get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
def insert_payout(payout):

     vals = [payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout,
        payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout,
        payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout, payout] #works

       sql = '''INSERT INTO test_db.public.test_node
       (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25, col26, col27, col28, col29, col30, col31, col32)
  VALUES
       (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) '''

  conn = None
 
     print(vals)#remove after testing
     try:
         # read database configuration
         params = setparams()#managed elsewhere just connects to the db working
         # connect to the PostgreSQL database
         conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
         # create a new cursor
         cur = conn.cursor()
         # execute the INSERT statement
         cur.execute(sql, vals)
         # commit the changes to the database
         conn.commit()
         # close communication with the database
         cur.close()
      except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
          print(error)
      finally:
          if conn is not None:
              conn.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         insert_payout(3.3)
```

An alternate form, using named arguments, would be:

```
vals = {"val": payout}
sql = '''INSERT INTO test_db.public.test_node
       (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21, col22, col23, col24, col25, col26, col27, col28, col29, col30, col31, col32)
  VALUES
      (%(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, 
%(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, 
%(val)s,%(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s, %(val)s)'''
```